# select where mapping id in array implode

Tags: mysql

```
+---------+----------+-----------
|   id    |   value  |  map_id  |
+---------+----------+-----------
|    1    |   avcne  |   1,2,3  |
+---------+----------+-----------
|    2    |   fdhsj  |   5,6,7  |
+---------+----------+-----------
|    3    |   kqrno  |   8,9,0  |
+---------+----------+-----------
```

FROm the table above

```
SELECT value FROM table_above where map_id = 2
```

Then the result would be 'avcne'.

```
SELECT values FROM table_above where map_id = 6
```

Then the result would be 'fdhsj'.

Is there any better way to do this without using `%-%` such as

```
SELECT value FROM table_above where map_id = %2%
```

Thanks in advance.

Note: this is just for a temporary table.

Comment: Bad DB design.. however check for `find_in_set` function of mysql.

Comment: Yes, I am sure this is not good. but this is for development purpose where data is still temporary. by the way, thanks for the reference.

Comment: nothing is temporary

Comment: lol, everything is temporary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL's [`find_in_set`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) is just what you're looking for:

```
SELECT value FROM table_above WHERE FIND_IN_SET(2, map_id)
```